# How to set a reminder in through AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarms

I want to make reminder in my Android application. I have taken date-picker and time-picker and stored the time and date in an SQLite database. Now I want to compare the date and time values from the database with the system date and time to provide reminder functionality (e.g. a birthday reminder).

So, how should I develop it? Can anyone suggest or give me some sample code covering this problem?

Comment: Please consider improving your question. What you are asking is too broad. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You should find a tutorial explaining this functionality, try it and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Is this your problem solved?